# Can't send email using Indy, freezes program

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, email-attachments, indy

When i try to send an email with attachment using indy my program freezes and i don't know why. 
Here's the full code for the form i'm using for sending emails.

```
unit Dok_sutisana;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, IdMessage, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase,
IdSMTP, StdCtrls, Buttons, ComCtrls, IdAttachmentFile;

type
TForm14 = class(TForm)
  Edit1: TEdit;
  Edit2: TEdit;
  Label1: TLabel;
  Label2: TLabel;
  BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
FontDialog1: TFontDialog;
RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
IdSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
procedure BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
 end;

var
 Form14: TForm14;

 implementation

 uses Autentif, EDGA;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm14.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if FontDialog1.Execute() then
RichEdit1.Font:=FontDialog1.Font;
end;

procedure TForm14.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var s:string;
begin
form3.ADOTable1.Active:=true;
//setup SMTP
IdSMTP1.Host := form3.adotable1['smtp'];
IdSMTP1.Port := form3.adotable1['ports'];
IdSMTP1.Username:= '******@gmail.com';
IdSMTP1.Password:='******';

//setup mail message
IdMessage1.From.Address := form3.adotable1['e-pasts'];
IdMessage1.From.Name:= form3.adotable1['Vards']+' '+ form3.adotable1['Uzvards'];
IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := edit1.Text;;

IdMessage1.Subject := edit2.Text;
IdMessage1.Body.Add(RichEdit1.Text + form3.ADOTable1['paraksts']);
s:= GetCurrentDir + form1.ADOTable1['Dok_adr'];
TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, s ) ;

//send mail

IdSMTP1.Connect() ;
IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1) ;
IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
IdMessage1.Free;
IdSMTP1.Free;

form3.ADOTable1.Active:=false;
Form14.Close;
end;

end.
```

I hope that whit this I can get some help for my problem.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger? Might help to know exactly what step is locking up. Also you will need try...finally around the connect/ disvonnect and the memory create / free. Might be that the first time through you connect but don't disconnect and then you will have to wait while the connect times out.

Comment: @DavidG the lock up happens in TIdSMTP.Connect function in IdSMTP

Comment: When I use this library I have additional lines: "IdSMTP1.NeedAuthentication := false;" and "IdSMTP1.UseTLS := emNOTLSSupport". I suspect you could try then first line before connect and see what happens.

Comment: Before your line "IdSMTP1.Connect" add "IdSMTP1.NeedAuthentication := false;". Note that you code could not compile with "Connect()" as this is not valid delphi pascal. You would need to provide actual code. Probably why the qustion is on hold.

Comment: @DavidG where exactly do I need to add them? (I don't know that much about all this)

Comment: Can you post your actual source code (including Creates of the Indy Components)? BTW I think my answer is not correct- sorry. Just digging through my code now.

Comment: @DavidG here's the full code from the form.

Comment: The connect() statement takes an optional parameter (-1 which I assume is indefinite wait). You could change the wait to a positive value say "30" for testing - might timeout in 30 seconds (?) with an exception. Next add an "OnStatus" event to IdSMTP1.OnStatus := OnStatus. You will need to create a method on your class

Comment: @DavidG can't write anything in connect(), can you explain what you mean with method in class, and if I add that line "OnStatus" then "OnStatus" is undeclared identifier.

Comment: @DavidG: `TIdSMTP` does not have a `NeedsAuthentication` property, the `UseTLS` property does not have an `emNOTLSSupport` value, and the `Connect()` method does not have an optional parameter for a timeout (use the `ConnectTimeout` property instead). This makes me think you are using a non-standard/customized version of Indy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry was looking at the version that came in Delphi 7 and got confused. Swapped to the Delphi2010 version when I got home.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh also, the Delphi 7 version did have some customization. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy uses blocking operations, and you are using Indy in the context of the main UI thread.  So while `TIdSMTP` is busy, your main thread is blocked from processing new messages, giving the appearance of an app freeze, until `TIdSMTP` is finished.

To avoid the freezing, you can either:

1. (preferred solution) Move your `TIdSMTP` code into a separate worker thread.
2. Drop a `TIdAntiFreeze` component onto your Form.  This will allow the main message queue to continue processing new messages while other Indy components are operating in the main thread.

For good measure, you should also set the `TIdSMTP.ConnectTimeout` and `TIdSMTP.ReadTimeout` properties so `Connect()` and `Send()` do not block for long periods of time.  If a timeout occurs, an appropriate exception will be raised to abort the operation.

Comment: I added `TIdAntiFreeze` and tried to send the email again. The program still didn't work, but I could press the Send button and an exception raised, that `EIdAlready connected`, and the program couldn't continue.

Comment: `EIdAlreadyConnected` is raised when you call `Connect()` while `Connected` is true. Keep in mind that `Connected` can be true even if the underlying socket is closed if the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` has unread data in it. So if you need to close the socket during an active connection and then reconnect, make sure to clear the `InputBuffer` before calling `Connect()` again.

Comment: If the connection happens why the message hasn't been sent?

Comment: There is no way to answer that given the limited details you have provided so far. Where is the actual freeze occurring? On the `Connect()` or on the `Send()`? What is the actual `Port` that you are connecting to?

Comment: the problem might have been with security, and i got my program running using code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734414/using-indy-10-smtp-with-office365)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the use of ADO from your code and used hard-coded values for my email accounts (removed for security reasons here - you can the placeholders replace with working accounts).

This code works - it sends an attachment.

I also:

- added a try / finally around the connection to ensure that it is released if the send throws an exception;
- added the ConnectTimeout option mentioned by Lemy;
- Cleared the email body. Before adding the new content (otherwise you end up with multiple copies of the test);
- Need to remove the previous attachment as well otherwise your second email ends up with the attachment from the first

  ```
  IdSMTP1.Host := '******';
  IdSMTP1.Port := 25;
  IdSMTP1.Username:= '******@gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Password:='******';
  IdMessage1.From.Address := '******';
  IdMessage1.From.Name:= '******';
  IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := '******';
  IdMessage1.Subject := '******';
  IdMessage1.Body.Clear; // Clear the email body
  IdMessage1.Body.Add('******');
  s:= GetCurrentDir + '\******';
  IdMessage1.MessageParts.Clear;
  TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, s ) ;

  IdSMTP1.ConnectTimeout := 2400 ;
  IdSMTP1.Connect();
  try
      IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1) ;
  finally
      IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
  ```

As this simple example works, your problem could be:

- incorrect email name / password / values from the table;
- anti-virus package preventing your program access to TCP;
- trying to use an email account not provided by your ISP

When I changed ISPs, the old one did not work (access requires SMTPS) but when I swapped to use the email account provided by my broadband supplier, this did not require SMTPS but worked on plain SMTP as it was inside their network and therefore trusted

Comment: While it's nice you went through all this effort, it doesn't answer the question. The proper answer is that Indy is blocking, so your code stops until the call to `IdSMTP1.Send` returns. Remy's answer has the correct information, which is either a separate thread or use of `TIdAntiFreeze` (in order of preference) to keep from blocking the main (UI) thread. (The poster's code sends an attachment, too; the question was about how to prevent it from freezing the user interface while it was doing so.)